# What is the equivalent of json.dumps() in json-c?

Tags: c, json

I am working in C, on `Windows 11` and trying to send a POST request to an API. The request body should be in JSON format. Thus I just installed json-c. In Python, I know that `json.dumps()` created valid JSON strings that can be `POST`ed. For example:

```py
text = 'στελιοσ'
json.dumps(text)
```

gives: `'"\\u03c3\\u03c4\\u03b5\\u03bb\\u03b9\\u03bf\\u03c3"'`

So, in `lib-c` I am doing:

```cpp
#include <json.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
char* text = "{\"key\":\"στελιοσ\"}";
struct json_object* jobj;

jobj = json_tokener_parse(text);
printf("jobj from str:\n---\n%s\n---\n", json_object_to_json_string_ext(jobj, JSON_C_TO_STRING_PLAIN));
}
```

and I get:

```
jobj from str:
---
{ "key": "???????" }
---
```

So, how can I get these escaped Greek characters in C, just like the appear in Python via `json.dumps()`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I am doing:

char* text = "{\"key\":\"στελιοσ\"}"` Uch, what compiler are you using? How do you know there are no `"????"` in the string in the first place? Please possible post full program sources, including `int main` and `#include` - guessing includes is no fun, and including compilation steps. `and I get: {"key":` did you get no `jobj from str:`? Please kindly post full output.

Comment: I copied and added `int main`  and relevant includes and compiled the code with just `-ljson-c` and it outputted `{"key":"στελιοσ"}` properly. I used gcc11.1 on linux. Can't reproduce. My guess would be that your compiler does not support embedding Unicode characters inside normal `"` strings. Try using wide sting `L""` and converting to multibyte string `wcstombs`. Remember to set your locale first.

Comment: I need it to output "\\u03c3\\u03c4\\u03b5\\u03bb\\u03b9\\u03bf\\u03c3" instead of στελιοσ, jut like Python does with json.dumps()